# Поиск по ListBox

Tags: delphi

Ребята, подскажите поиск по ЛистБоксу. Необходимо, чтобы в `Edit` вписывалось слово и, если такое словое есть, то игнорировать, а если нету, то добавить в `ListBox`.
Буду очень признателен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю как в старых версиях, но в последней Delphi XE2 регистр при сравнении не учитывается. Поэтому такой код работает без проблем:

```
  if ListBox1.Items.IndexOf(Edit1.Text) < 0 then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(Edit1.Text);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень Вы меня выручили

Comment: Не за что, всегда приятно помочь человеку стремящемуся к знаниям!

Answer (score 1):

поиск в листбоксе:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
//поиск в списке
Listbox1.Perform(LB_SELECTSTRING, -1, longint(Pchar(Edit1.text)));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var
  strigns : TStringList;
begin
  strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    strings.CaseSensitive := False;
    strings.Assign( listBox.Items );
    if ( strings.IndexOf( edit.Text ) < 0 ) then
      listBox.Items.Add( edit.Text );
  finally
    string.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Нет необходимости в TStringList. Можно работать непосредственно с ListBox.

Comment: разве TListBox.Items нечувствителен к регистру?

Comment: @maxionans, <a href="http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/faq_delphi_basics/AnsiUpperCase.php.html">AnsiUpperCase</a>

Comment: Sh4dow, да, можно пройтись циклом применив AnsiUpperCase к каждому элементу, но что из этого, какое преимущество перед приведенным методом? Давайте по существу, а не лишь бы 5 копеек вставить.

Comment: Эм, а Assign не копирует ли содержание в себя?